# Moving a register into an index of an array in x86 assembly language

Tags: x86, masm

I'm trying to move the `bl` register into an array of bytes in x86 assembly language, but the following statement produces an error message from the masm assembler.

`mov arr[2], bl` produces the output `1>p4.asm(48): error A2101: cannot add two relocatable labels`.

Is it possible to move a register into an array in x86 assembly language?

Comment: I've spent days searching for an answer to this question, and I've found no answers yet.

Comment: `bx` is a 16bit register, that is bigger than a byte, if you need only a byte contained in `bx`, you need to access `bl` its lower 8 bits part

Comment: @Seki I've fixed that part now, but I'm still trying to find out how to move a register into a specific index of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically something that the following should work for a hard coded index value:

```
mov byte ptr [arr + 2], bl  ;store bl
```

The `[]` are optional: [Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129743/confusing-brackets-in-masm32)

For a more generic way:

```
mov si, 2                ;your index
mov al, bl               ;bl = byte value from your question
mov bx, offset arr
mov byte ptr [bx+si], al
```

Comment: `mov byte ptr [ax], bl` produces this error: `1>p4.asm(54): error A2031: must be index or base register`

Comment: sorry, while I can read quite easily assembly I am a bit rusty to write some myself. I forget that the `mov byte ptr` must use a base (bx / bp) or an index (si / di) register. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

If we use an instruction with an immediate-operand, then we have to specify how many bytes our operand will be obtain. Therefore we have to use a keyword like **byte**, **word**, or **dword** for to inform the assembler how many following bytes of the ram location we want to acess.

```
mov byte ptr[bx+si], 01h
mov word ptr[bx+si], 0001h
mov dword ptr[bx+si], 00000001h
```

But if we use a register as an operand (with it known among of bytes), then we do not need it to specify (for to become a smaller listing with an easier overview).

```
mov [bx+si], al
mov al, [bx+si]

mov [bx+si], ax
mov ax, [bx+si]
```

**Exception** with MASM and with a DWORD-Register as an operand.

```
mov dword ptr[bx+si], eax
mov eax, dword ptr[bx+si]
```

Dirk